# Show print preview in Telerik reportiviewer when it loads

Tags: c#, telerik

I am using the Telerik ReportViewer and would like to display it in "Print preview" imediatly without the user having to click on the PP icon. Is this possible?

EDIT:
I have a Telerik report viewer which is inside a silverlight child window. When the report loads it is displayed not how it is going to be printed out (print preview mode). I would like to programaticaly set the window state to "Print preview" instead of having the user first click on the print preview icon to see how it's going to look on paper

Comment: Could you elaborate on your question a little bit more please for clarity.

Comment: Telerik support is really good, you didn't copy/link them in on this q & A did you?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have you tried setting the ViewMode?

[Telerik Reporting R2 2016 | ReportViewer.ViewMode Property](http://www.telerik.com/help/reporting/p_telerik_reportviewer_silverlight_reportviewer_viewmode.html)

If you are creating this control in XAML, then it would look something like:

```
<telerik:ReportViewer ViewMode="PrintPreview" />
```

Comment: I a msuing Q3 2011 where this feature isn't available. I'll donwload the latest version and then use this. Thanks!

Comment: @IvanCrojachKaračić - did the upgrade give you what you needed?